# Django, 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I'm getting this attribute error when I am trying to import views from django.contrib.auth, and I wanna use their authentication method

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url,include
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs= 
{'next_page':'/' }),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'

url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),

Answer (score 3):

[Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py)  auth.view module doesn't have `login` function.

Try this (Django 2.2)

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, logout_then_login, LogoutView


url(r'^accounts/login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^accounts/logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

or 

url(r'^accounts/login/$', logout_then_login, name='login'),
```